# Desired capabilities in webdriver ruby bindings

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm using selenium grid with my tests wrote in ruby/watir/cucumber to speed up by parallelization. I have some nodes in my grid which I would like to use during working day, and some nodes I would like to use only during night. I think that it can be achieved by using of applicationName capabilitie. 
Now my code looks limke this:

```
@driver= FigNewton.browser
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 360
@env = ENV['ENV']
@env ||= 'local'
if @env == 'local' then
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new @driver , :http_client => client
else
  @hub_url = ENV['HUB_URL']
  @hub_url ||= 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url=>"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => @driver.downcase.to_sym)
end
```

But there is no way to change applicationName when I set capabilities in this way. 
So I tried to use the next code:

```
@driver= FigNewton.browser
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 360
@env = ENV['ENV']
@env ||= 'local'
if @env == 'local' then
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new @driver , :http_client => client
else
  @hub_url = ENV['HUB_URL']
  @hub_url ||= 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox
  caps[:applicationName] = "test" 
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url=>"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => caps)
end
```

My node is started with the next command:

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node -host testHost  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxSession 20 -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=10 -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=10,applicationName=test
```

But when I use the second approach I've got the next exception:

```
Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{platform=ANY, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, applicationName=test, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, takesScreenshot=true, version=}] (org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

Can't figure out what is wrong.

Is there any other way to filter nodes in the grid?

Comment: i don't think there is a way to filter nodes or tell the hub on which node to run. why not, just connect each node cluster to different hub?

Comment: Based on selenium capabilities matcher it's consider aplicationName as capability, so I think it's possible:
 
    public DefaultCapabilityMatcher() {
        toConsider.add(CapabilityType.PLATFORM);
        toConsider.add(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME);
        toConsider.add(CapabilityType.VERSION);
        toConsider.add("applicationName");
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found [Undocumented way to select a node on a Selenium Grid2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/PRsEBcbpNlM), hope it helps

> NODE1:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role node -hub http://HUB_IP:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=11,maxInstances=1,platform=WINDOWS,applicationName=windows7_32bits_firefox_11
```

> NODE2:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role node -hub http://HUB_IP:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=11,maxInstances=1,platform=WINDOWS,applicationName=windows7_64bits_firefox_11
```

> In your tests you have to add 
>   "applicationName=windows7_32bits_firefox_11" to your desired 
>   capabilities array.

Comment: Doesn't work for me so I ended up writing my own CapabilityMatcher.